# Linq Query for XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML as below

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Address>
          <City>Bangalore</City>
          <CreatedOn>1-1-2012</CreatedOn>
        </Address>
        <Address>
          <City>Pune</City>
          <CreatedOn>1-10-2012</CreatedOn>
        </Address>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Address>
          <City>Hyd</City>
          <CreatedOn>1-1-2009</CreatedOn>
        </Address>
        <Address>
          <City>Bombay</City>
          <CreatedOn>1-1-2010</CreatedOn>
        </Address>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to have a linq query in C# to retrive the Employee record with address node which has the latest createon date.

Can you please help me how to write the Linq Query.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Cmon! Try to google it :) There are a LOT of sampes.

Comment: tl;dr 3rd world developers wanting us to do their homework for them despite developers never having it so easy to get answers to these trivial problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
string xml="<Employees><Employee><ID>1</ID><Address><City>Bangalore</City><CreatedOn>1-1-2012</CreatedOn></Address><Address><City>Pune</City><CreatedOn>1-10-2012</CreatedOn></Address></Employee><Employee><ID>2</ID><Address><City>Hyd</City><CreatedOn>1-1-2009</CreatedOn></Address><Address><City>Bombay</City><CreatedOn>1-1-2010</CreatedOn></Address></Employee></Employees>";

XElement xe = XElement.Parse(xml);

var query = xe
.Elements("Employee")
.Select
(
    x=> new 
    {
        Addresses = x.Elements("Address")
        .Select
        (
            z=>new 
            {
                ID = x.Element("ID").Value,
                City = z.Element("City").Value,
                CreatedOn = z.Element("CreatedOn").Value
            }
        ).ToList()
    }
)
.SelectMany (X=>X.Addresses);

var record = query.Where (q => DateTime.Parse(q.CreatedOn)==query.Max (x => DateTime.Parse(x.CreatedOn))).SingleOrDefault ();

Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",record.ID,record.City,record.CreatedOn);
```

Comment: It doesn't returns anything...

Comment: I missed the part about the where....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This will return only 1 address values. But I want the distinct employee with latest created on address. Can you please help me in getting this as in output